# Can I make the toc show up for documents with `header_footer` as false?

Tags: ruby, asciidoctor

I'm embedding some adoc files in a webpage and so I don't want to have the full `header_footer` stuff (with `html`/`body`/etc...), but that seems to be the only way that I can get the table of contents to display in an adoc file when converting it with the asciidoctor gem.  Is there a way to have both?  I tried looking at the source code but didn't see anything off-hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think that [this answer written by Dan Allen about Jekyll](http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Jekyll-Plugin-toc-Problem-tp4070p4071.html) is also valid in your case:

> In that scenario, the only toc position available are "preamble" and "macro". The first puts the toc in the preamble, the second at the location of the toc::[] macro. I usually recommend using the toc macro.

Comment: I don't really have control over the adoc files, unfortunately, because they are being submitted to the site.  I'll probably try pre-processing the adoc files to change `:toc:` to `toc::[]` or perhaps generate my own TOC as Dan suggests.  Either way this answers my question, thanks!